# Adding newline characters to unix shell variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a variable in a shell script in which I'd like to format the data. The variable stores new data during every iteration of a loop. Each time the new data is stored, I'd like to insert a new line character. Here is how I'm trying to store the data into the variable.

`VARIABLE="$VARIABLE '\n' SomeData"`

Unfortunately, the output includes the literal `'\n'` Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try `$'\n'`:

```
VAR=a
VAR="$VAR"$'\n'b
echo "$VAR"
```

gives me

```
a
b
```

Comment: Thanks vmpstr. I may be mistaken, but I believe `VAR=$VAR$'\n'b` must be surrounded by double quotes. Which results in a literal '\n'.

Comment: You can switch between different kinds of quotes in the same "word": `VAR="$VAR"$'\n'"some data"` has `$VAR` in double-quotes, `\n` in `$''` so it'll get interpreted as a newline, and then `some data` back in double-quotes.  As long as there's no space between them, they'll all be concatenated together and the result assigned to VAR.

Comment: Thanks, I added double quotes around $VAR so that the existing newlines are preserved

Comment: The output of echo is different than how the values are being stored in VARIABLE. The contents of VARIABLE are passed to an email util. I am not echoing the data to command line. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I got it! Turns out I had some spacing issues. Thanks to everyone who cared to comment, especially Gordon Davisson. Here was my issue:

Original Code: `VAR="$VAR"$'\n'"Audit Source: $B Audit Path: $C"`

The spaces for formatting was messing things up.

New Code:`VAR="$VAR"$'\n'"Audit Source:$B"$'\t'"Audit Path:$C"`

No spaces here! Anyone know why the spacing causes issues? Even though the Original Code has everything surrounded by "?

Comment: Side note: all the solutions here (with the exeption of `printf`) won't work smoothly if your first character pair has a hash sign in it, c.f. this markdown header `FOO="# Markdown Title #"` would get split into two lines. I'm curious if there's another way.

Comment: Please note in your answer that this only works with Bash (and maybe some other shells that I don't know of). This solution is not generic, not everyone uses Bash.

Answer (score 21):

A common technique is:

```
nl='
'
VARIABLE="PreviousData"
VARIABLE="$VARIABLE${nl}SomeData"

echo "$VARIABLE"
PreviousData
SomeData
```

Also common, to prevent inadvertently having your string start with a newline:

```
VARIABLE="$VARIABLE${VARIABLE:+$nl}SomeData"
```

(The expression `${VARIABLE:+$nl}` will expand to a newline if and only if VARIABLE is set and non-empty.)

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is absolutely the canonical way to inject newlines into a variable.

Comment: The reason is is common is likely because people don't know about $'\n'. edit: I had originally downvoted but decided to just stick with a comment instead.

Comment: @jordanm Or more likely because people are aware that \n only works in a limited number of shells, while this technique will work in all shells.

Comment: Recommend enclosing the variables in quotes.  While `bash` may be OK, most shells will not be OK.

Comment: Doesn't the entire value need to be double quoted in order to append `SomeData` to `VARIABLES`

Such as `VAR="$VARIABLE${nl}SomeData"`


In this answer, there are two separate variables (`VAR` and `VARIABLE` I'm trying to append `VARIABLE`  to `VARIABLE`

Comment: @James  The double quotes are not strictly necessary, but if VARIABLE contains whitespace or shell special characters it is probably advisable to use them.  The VAR in the answer should read VARIABLE; my initial response was sloppy.

Comment: Thanks William. I've discovered that the output of echo is different than how the data is actually stored in VARIABLE. I need to take the contents of VARIABLE and pass it to an email util. Which means I wont be able to use echo. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

```
VAR="one"
VAR="$VAR.\n.two"
echo -e $VAR
```

#### Output:

> one.
>   
>   .two

Comment: Thanks Alex. I think when you echo here, the output is on multiple lines. But I think the variable is still be stored on one line? I'm not sure.

Comment: You're correct, `-e` makes echo treat escaped characters as special characters, without `-e` you would see entire value on one line with "\n" in the middle

Comment: Unfortunately I'm storing data in VAR and then sending the contents of VAR to an email utility. So the value can't be echoed, it must be formatted within the var itself. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Other than `$'\n'` you can use `printf` also like this:

```
VARIABLE="Foo Bar"
VARIABLE=$(printf "${VARIABLE}\nSomeData")
echo "$VARIABLE"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Foo Bar
SomeData
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava. But like the answer below, the output of echo is different than how the values are being stored in VARIABLE. The contents of VARIABLE are passed to an email util. I am not echoing the data to command line. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with all the other solutions: when using a `#` followed by `SPACE` (quite common when writing in Markdown) both would get split onto a new line.

So, another way of doing it would involve using single quotes so that the "\n" get rendered.

```
FOO=$'# Markdown Title #\n'
BAR=$'Be *brave* and **bold**.'
FOOBAR="$FOO$BAR"

echo "$FOOBAR"
```

**Output:**

```
# Markdown Title #
Be *brave* and **bold**.
```

Answer (score 2):

> Single quote All special characters between these quotes lose their
>   special meaning.
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-quoting-mechanisms.htm

So the syntax you use does something different that you want to achieve.

This is what you need:

> The $'\X' construct makes the -e option in echo unnecessary.
>   
> https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/escapingsection.html

```
echo -e "something\nsomething"
```

or

```
echo "something"$'\n'"something"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot simpler than you think:

```
VARIABLE="$VARIABLE
SomeData"
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the first two solutions, I'd do like shown below. Concatenating strings with the '+=' operator, somehow looks clearer to me.

Also rememeber to use printf as opposed to echo, you will save yourself so much trouble

```
sometext="This is the first line"
sometext+=$'\n\n'
sometext+="This is the second line AFTER the inserted new lines"
printf '%s' "${sometext}"
```

Outputs:

> This is the first line
>
> This is the third line AFTER the inserted new line

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `echo` command, in ash you have to use the option `-e` to expand special characters. This should work for you:

```
VAR="First line"
VAR="$VAR\nSecond line"
echo -e $VAR
```

This outputs

```
First line
Second line
```